# Creating strings of X length based on array

Tags: php, arrays, strlen

I would like to iterate over an array and from that array create a string. 
However, each string needs to be of certain size (500 bytes).

So my array looks like:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [name] => shirt
            [price] => 1.25
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [name] => car
            [price] => 25.10
        )
    ...
)

$str = "";

foreach($arr as $v) {
    $str .= "<name>".$v['name']."</name>";
    $str .= "<price>".$v['price']."</price>";
}
```

Output should be something like:

```
str1 = '<name>shirt</name><price>1.25</price><name>car</name><price>25.10</price>...' // until 500 bytes or less. 
str2 = '<name>shirt</name><price>1.25</price><name>car</name><price>25.10</price>...' // until 500 bytes or less.
```

// I need complete tags. So I can't have a string that looks like:

```
str = '<name>flower</name><pri';
```

Comment: Why not tell us why are doing this and let us show you the correct way?

Comment: basically, I need strings that contain both tags, `<name>` and `<price>`. So I would like to push as many array elements  into a string. But since I know the array has a lot of elements, and I also know that each strings has to be shorter than 500 bytes, then is likely I'll need several strings.

Comment: You either need 500-character long strings, or you need strings that abide by tag boundaries. You cannot have both.

Comment: can you please elaborate a bit more about that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Save each segment to as less than 500 characters.

```
$xml = array();
$str = '';
foreach($arr as $v)
{
    $temp = "<name>".$v['name']."</name>";
    $temp .= "<price>".$v['price']."</price>";

    if(mb_strlen($str . $temp) > 500)
    {
        $xml[] = $str;
        $str = '';
    }
    $str = $temp;
}
$xml[] = $str;

print_r($xml);
```

Answer (score 1):

[str_split](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.str-split.php) sounds like a good candidate.

Comment: Good default, but that looks like XML above which will be invalid if it's split like this.

Comment: You are right. I was thinking Kayla wanted to stream the output in small chunks.

Comment: the issue with `str_split`, is that it will break the string at the wrong place. all strings should contain both tags: `name`, `price`